# How to install textract in python3

Tags: python-3.5, text-extraction

```
sudo python3 -m pip install textract
sudo apt-get install textract
pip install textract
sudo apt-get install swig
```

I want to install textract in python3 but it is not install proper way, it gives the following error.

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.o -Wno-unused-label -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-result -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-misleading-indentation
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DSPHINXBASE_EXPORTS -DPOCKETSPHINX_EXPORTS -DSPHINX_DLL -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_pulse.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_pulse.o -Wno-unused-label -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-result -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-misleading-indentation
  deps/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad/ad_pulse.c:44:30: fatal error: pulse/pulseaudio.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the source file for textract from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textract
2. pip3 install pdfminer3k
3. untar the downloaded file
4. cd into the directory
5. run: python3 setup.py install

Comment: When I try to install pdfminer3k I get "error: Setup script exited with error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1"
I tried to install swig with brew but without success

Answer (score 5):

You will need to install the `libpulse-dev` in Ubuntu or `pulseaudio-libs-devel` in Fedora first.

- If you are in Ubuntu try `sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev`
- If you are in Fedora try `sudo dnf install pulseaudio-libs-devel`

At least this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

First install pip in conda. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

then install textract, `pip install textract`

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but instead of pip you should check out conda it's much more encapsulated in regards to installing this package.

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge textract
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 textract
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 textract
```

Source:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/textract

Comment: the first line did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using the following command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract.git
```